# jQuery Ajax query display List in Table

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I think a picture is gonna explain my problem better.

[image: error]

I need this ( " Object Appel d'Offre : [ La Fourniture et installation ] ")

to be shown only once.

The jQuery Code :

```
$(document).on("click","#bt_search",function (e) {
        $.ajax({
                    url : '/Lots/Search',
                    type : 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data : {  RefAO : $("#RefAppelOffre").val()  },
                    success : function(list) {
                        if(list == "fail"){

                            alert('error');

                        }
                        else{

                            $.each(list, function (i) {

                               $("#titreAppend").append("<h3 style='margin-top:55px'>Object Appel d'Offre  : [ <u style='color:#f43030'><b> " + list[i].Objet + "</b></u> ] </h3>");
                               $("#tab tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                                            "<td>" + list[i].Ref_Lot + "</td>" +
                                                            "<td>" + list[i].Titre + "</td>" +
                                                            "<td>" + list[i].TotalLotTTC + "</td>" +
                                                            "<td>" + list[i].NombreConcurrent + "</td>" +
                                                            "<td>" + list[i].NombreArticle + "</td>" +
                                                        "</tr>");
                            })

                        }//Fermeture Else
                    }//Fermeture Success

               })//fermeture ajax {}               

 })
```

The Asp.net Back Code :

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Search(string RefAO)
    {

        var list = GlobalVariables.ctx.GetDetailedListLots(RefAO).ToList<GetDetailedListLots_Result>();
        //var list = ctx.Bilan_Lot(RefAO).ToList<Bilan_Lot_Result>();
        if(list != null)
        {

            return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        else
        {
            return Json("fail");
        }

    }
```

I know it's obvious that the title I am printing is going to be appended each time, can anybody give me a solution for this?

Comment: can you provide complete code or some live demo where we can try something?

Comment: Can't you move the title appending line of code outside the .each?

Comment: @Hosney i have tried that but it still prints that twice because the list returned 2 rows

Comment: If both rows have the same Objet value you could just do a list[0].Objet and move it out of the .each scope.

Comment: Please check my answer. The idea is to drop a flag named `hasTitle` and update it once you have printed the title and check if it has been printed _before_ printing it.

Comment: @Hosney yes that's what i did but the same result remains

Comment: @RedaRACHID it shouldn't be called twice unless the ajax call is made twice. Something else might be wrong here.

Comment: Why not try $("#bt_search").click(function(){}) instead?

Comment: @Hosney yeah i have already used that , this is frusturating

Comment: Can you include the html too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#bt_search").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url : '/Lots/Search',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {  RefAO : $("#RefAppelOffre").val()  },
        success : function(list) {
            if(list == "fail") {
                alert('error');
            }
            else {
                if (list.length) {
                    $("#titreAppend").append("<h3 style='margin-top:55px'>Object Appel d'Offre  : [ <u style='color:#f43030'><b> " + list[0].Objet + "</b></u> ] </h3>");
                }
                $.each(list, function (i) {                
                   $("#tab tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                                "<td>" + list[i].Ref_Lot + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + list[i].Titre + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + list[i].TotalLotTTC + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + list[i].NombreConcurrent + "</td>" +
                                                "<td>" + list[i].NombreArticle + "</td>" +
                                            "</tr>");
                })

            }//Fermeture Else
        }//Fermeture Success

   })//fermeture ajax {}               
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
    var hasTitle = false;
    $.each(list, function (i) {
        if(! hasTitle) {
           $("#titreAppend").append("<h3 style='margin-top:55px'>Object Appel d'Offre  : [ <u style='color:#f43030'><b> " + list[i].Objet + "</b></u> ] </h3>");
           hasTitle = true; // Ensure title is printed only once
        }

       $("#tab tbody").append("<tr>" +
                                    "<td>" + list[i].Ref_Lot + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + list[i].Titre + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + list[i].TotalLotTTC + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + list[i].NombreConcurrent + "</td>" +
                                    "<td>" + list[i].NombreArticle + "</td>" +
                                "</tr>");
    })
```

Comment: If you are still seeing it twice, chances are, your ajax request is firing twice. Can you add a `console.log('Handling request')` inside your `success` callback and see how many times it is called?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
var titreAppend = $("#titreAppend");
            var tabtbody = $("#tab tbody");

            $.each(list, function (index, object) {

                titreAppend.append("<h3 style='margin-top:55px'>Object Appel d'Offre  : [ <u style='color:#f43030'><b> " + object.Objet + "</b></u> ] </h3>");
                tabtbody.append("<tr>" +
                                             "<td>" + object.Ref_Lot + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + object.Titre + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + object.TotalLotTTC + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + object.NombreConcurrent + "</td>" +
                                             "<td>" + object.NombreArticle + "</td>" +
                                         "</tr>");
            });
```

Comment: still the same result !

Comment: use 
return Json(new{ list = list}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

and check what you are getting in jquery list variable